# ASP/HTML/CSS - Design View Different from Browser Preview

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I'm getting a difference in my design view and what the actual preview displays. I'm pretty sure my code is correctly reflecting what appears in the design view, but incorrectly in the browser preview. Any suggestions on how I can fix this and why this is happening? The black content area should be below the header and buttons.

Master Page Design View: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/30/designview.jpg/

Browser Preview: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/638/browserpreviewz.jpg/

IE and Chrome both display the same behavior.

Here is the code of the master page: 
(because of '<' I'm having getting asp code in here...how do I enter it in as code sample?)

Comment: wrap your code using the {} button the textbox for posting the code..

Comment: Never trust design view! Test in browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I find i can never trust the web preview in visual Studio, so while this is not really an answer to your specific question I recommend you always use an actual browser for preview. :)

Comment: Then why does design view exist? I'm completely baffled as to the purpose of design view if it only gives you a false impression of what your site will look like. ~Signed, Dazed and Confused.

Comment: That makes two of us! Microsoft themselves just call it "near-WYSIWYG"! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4c64s41%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS might be cached. When you are looking at the web preview, It is worth a try to reload the page and the CSS by clicking ctrl-F5 (not just F5). This worked for me a few times when I felt that my CSS changes are not being rendered in the web preview.